# Почему выводится неверная сумма?

Tags: c, матрицы

Функция должна подсчитывать сумму строки из матрицы. Подсчет верный, кроме 1 строки, скрин:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот фрагмент кода, почему вывод 27, а не 22?

```
#define x 5
#define y 2
   
int main()
{
    int ** a = (int**)calloc(x, sizeof(int* ));
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        a[i] = (int*)calloc(y, sizeof(int));

    input_matrix(a, x, y);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        printf("%d\n", sum_row(a[i], y));

}

int sum_row(int* p, int n)
{
    int sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += *(p+i);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Локальные переменные надо инициализировать.

Замените

```
int sum;
```

на

```
int sum = 0;
```

Comment: ааа, какой раз попадаюсь. Спасибо!